# InvalidCastException when casting IList<T> to IList

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm trying to implement a Sort method for an `IList<T>`, with the following code:

```
public static void Sort<T>(this IList<T> list, Comparison<T> comparison)
{
    ArrayList.Adapter((IList)list).Sort(Comparer<T>.Create(comparison));
}
```

I'm calling the method for a list of elements of a known type, and providing this comparison fuction:

```
cardwraplayout.Children.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    Card card1 = Cards.FindCardByIconId(x.Id);
    Card card2 = Cards.FindCardByIconId(x.Id);
    int result = card1.Rarity.CompareTo(card2.Rarity);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        result = card1.Name.CompareTo(card2.Name);
    }
    return result;
});
```

When I call the above method, an `InvalidCastException` occurs at this line:`ArrayList.Adapter((IList)list).Sort(Comparer<T>.Create(comparison));`:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Why can't I cast my `IList<T>` to `IList` in order to implement my own sort function?

Update 1:
Tried changing `Comparer<T>` to `Comparer<object>`, still throws the same exception.

```
public static void Sort<T>(this IList<T> list, Comparison<object> comparison)
{
    ArrayList.Adapter((IList)list).Sort(Comparer<object>.Create(comparison));
}

Image img1;
Image img2;

cardwraplayout.Children.Sort((x,y) =>
{
    img1 = (Image)x;
    img2 = (Image)y;
    Card card1 = Cards.FindCardByIconId(img1.Id);
    Card card2 = Cards.FindCardByIconId(img2.Id);
    int result = card1.Rarity.CompareTo(card2.Rarity);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        result = card1.Name.CompareTo(card2.Name);
    }
    return result;
});
```

Update 2:
Creating a Comparer class won't work because I need to access several fields from another class, which will give me the following error:

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property "Cards"

Comment: There's no implicit cast that can be made from `IList` to `IList<T>` AFAIK. The 2 interfaces are simply not compatible. You could just do `list.ToArray().Sort...`

Comment: @apokryfos would that modify my IList or create a new Array? Clearing & re-populating the list again is too expensive.

Comment: Can you post the exception please?

Comment: @apokryfos Should I ask a separate question about how I can sort an IList<T>, in that case ?

Comment: Actually problem is you need to use an `object` comparer not a `T` comparer. I somehow missed that

Comment: @apokryfos Not a duplicate of that. The accepted answer there provides the same problematic code the OP is asking about here.

Comment: @hvd you're right, though when I noted that I thought the issue was that OP was using `Comparer<T>` but that was apparently half the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't I cast my `IList<T>` to `IList` in order to implement my own sort function?

It depends on the concrete type of the list that you receive. `IList<T>` does not implement `IList`. Concrete classes can choose to implement `IList<T>` and `IList`, to implement only `IList<T>`, to implement only `IList`, or to implement neither. There is no inherent relation between the two just because they share the name.

For example:

- [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Collection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx) implement both.
- [`ArraySegment<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx) implements only `IList<T>`, not `IList`.
- [`StringCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) implements only `IList`, not `IList<string>`.

By casting to `IList`, you're telling the compiler "It's okay, I know more than you, I know the class I've got really does implement `IList`." But the class in this case didn't implement `IList`. Hence the failure.

To sort an `IList<T>`, create something that works for `IList<T>`, don't try to get something that was made for `IList` to work. For instance, you could copy everything into a `T[]`, call `Array.Sort`, and copy back the results. (That's actually more efficient than what `ArrayList.Adapter(...).Sort(...)` would have done anyway.) Or you could hand-code one of the standard search algorithms.

Comment: That worked, but it's inefficient (since the IList<T> i'm modifying is readonly - although mutable, I have to clear and manually re-add the array contents)

Comment: @NicodeOry If you're able to modify it, surely it's not read-only? I don't understand what you mean there.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Forms and modifying the children of a layout. Apparently, their API is designed so you can't do `layout.Children = myArray` but you can however do `layout.Children.Add(item)`.

Comment: @NicodeOry Ah, okay, that's a pretty special case. Normally, for `IList<T>`, you'd be able to simply set a specific index to a value, but that might not work there. In that special case though, you might be able to avoid mutating `IList<T>` operations entirely by sorting in a copy of the array, and then calling `RaiseChild` for each element in that array.

Comment: That's a great idea! I hadn't thought of that. I'll try that and post back.